# Should methods that return shared_ptrs be const?

Tags: c++

I have an object that has `vector<shared_ptr>`'s to member objects. One of the methods on the parent object is `vector<shared_ptr<Object>> readObjects()`. I expect the caller of readObjects to modify the objects through the pointer. On one hand, the method call itself doesn't make any logical change to the objects. On the other, these objects could be modified through the shared_ptr(and thus the parent object).

Should this method be const or not?

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens when you declare such a method `const` and attempt to modify the referenced objects through the `shared_ptr`s?

Comment: Do you consider the pointed at objects as part of the state of the parent object? Do you want a const qualifier on one of the parent objects to ensure that the pointed at objects are also const?

Comment: @JAB It compiles. It's not a matter of things working or not, but what is the "right" thing to do for the purpose of const correctness.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yes, I consider the pointed at objects part of the state. I want the objects themselves to be modified.

Comment: Then the method should not be const. If it's const, then that would allow the state of a const object to change.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Please make a comment of your answer so I can accept it.